# USB keyboards repeat rate seem slower than PS/2

Tags: usb, keyboard, performance, repeat-rate

Long ago, I've had a PS/2 keyboard but lately have switched to USB keyboards, namely Microsoft Comfort Curve and then Microsoft Natural 4000.

What I've noticed is that these USB keyboards have quite slower repeat rates than PS/2 keyboards. I always set repeat rate to maximum since I use arrow keys much, in text editors, in Total Commander and in this very edit field. So it's sometimes annoying that I scroll through text slower than before.

So, does anyone know of a way to raise the repeat rate on these keyboards? Or is it caused by the hardware?

Note than IntelliType software is not installed. I've set it up previously but the rate is not affected by it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

> In **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard** the values
>   *KeyboardDelay* and *KeyboardSpeed* control how long you hold a key before repeating
>   starts and how fast the repeat rate is when it does
>   start. The former ranges from 0 to 3, the latter from 0 to 31. BUT I'm
>   pretty sure Windows won't accept a rate past 31 and of course the
>   delay can't be less than 0.
>
> The key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard**
>   Response may prove to be more useful. The user reports good results
>   from these values:
>
> ```
> "AutoRepeatDelay"="200"
> "AutoRepeatRate"="15"
> "BounceTime"="0"
> "DelayBeforeAcceptance"="6"
> "Flags"="59"
> ```