# How to increase Windows keyboard repeat rate to match much faster Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, keyboard

I am a Windows 7 user at the office, but a KDE/Linux user at home.  I have noticed the keyboard repeat rate on Linux is much higher than Windows, maybe 50%.  Both the Linux command prompt and KDE/X11 apps can move the cursor (repeat keys) much faster than Windows.

- This affects both Windows XP and Windows 7.
- My Windows keyboard repeat rate are set the maximum.
- I am using the **same** model keyboard (Microsoft  Natural 4000) on my office PC and home PC.  Both are connected using USB.
- My Linux PC has a weaker CPU than my Windows PC (but I don't think that matters).

-

1. Has anyone else noticed this issue?
2. How can I turn my Windows keyboard repeat rate ["up to eleven"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven)?

[image: Spinal Tap - Up to Eleven]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/172364/usb-keyboards-repeat-rate-seem-slower-than-ps-2?rq=1 Aside from showing how to set these values, this page also hints that a PS/2 keyboard may just work faster (if that is an option for you).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11056655/1058320) answer on SO indicates that key repeat rate in Windows can be set with a system call - and provides a utility for doing so.

Comment: How is the photo relevant to the question? Anyway try timing the key repeat by moving the cursor through a large wall of text (holding down the right arrow key). Do this experiment in the different OSes you have and post the results. :)

Comment: Tip: In KDE systemsettings, you can see your keyboard delay/repeat settings, *in actual numbers*! If you happen to memorize your favourite settings, as I did, you can easily set them consistently across machines, and you'll always get precisely what you're used to. Thanks to this ability, I have no problem using insanely fast settings (160ms / 45Hz), because my settings are always precisely the same everywhere … reason enough to use KDE also at work, at least for me.